# No module named selenium (and not in folder, even though installation was successful)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried installing Selenium via pip using "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install selenium" and it was successful.

However, when trying to run the module, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Gedaka.py", line 1, in <module>
from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

So when trying to install it again, I get:

> Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in c:\python27\lib\site-packages

However, there's no Selenium in that folder or C:\python27 at all. I tried looking for solutions but didn't find any relevant or working ones. Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: so you cannot cd to `c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium `?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Nope, system can't find the path specified.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my firewall was sandboxing the installation of Selenium. Solved!